# Link to repository file in Issues

Tags: redmine

I'm using Redmine 2.1.2 and I want to create a link from an Issue to a file in the repository.

In the wiki I can do this very easily by `source:path/to/file`. But this doesn't work in the Issues.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create Custom field of Link format
2. Set it's name (ex. 'Repository link')
3. Set URL feld as `/redmine/projects/%project_id%/repository/show/%value%` (for syntax look here - http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineCustomFields)